# Is there an alternative to AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnnrwap?

Tags: c#, assemblies, appdomain

I'm trying to load a plugin, a class from a loaded assembly, in a specific AppDomain, but want to avoid having my plugins descend from MarshalByRefObject.

`Activator.CreateInstance(t)` crashed.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance(t) crashed. How did it crash? Got any stack trace? Code snippet of what you are doing? Why an alternative? Why not fix the crash?

Comment: @Snixtor I'm not trying to access the object across application domain boundaries. This application domain was created for the purpose of isolating the plugins from the main application domain.

Comment: If you're not trying to access across appdomain boundaries, then I wouldn't be loading it in a "specific appdomain", otherwise you're somewhat tied to needing "to access the object across application domain boundaries". The *correct* (MS mandated) way to do plugins is to use MEF. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Per MSDN, MarshalByRefObject "Enables access to objects across application domain boundaries". "Objects that do not inherit from MarshalByRefObject are implicitly marshal by value". And "Types must inherit from MarshalByRefObject when the type is used across application domain boundaries". Looks to me like you're stuck with MarshalByRefObject - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Give up with your home-brewed plugin system and use the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) instead.